# Unable to Cast COM object system to adodb recordset

Tags: c#, dll, com

I compiled a project with custom dll and ran fine on my machine running Windows 7 but when i put it on a machine running windows Server 2008, I get this error:

unable to cast com object of type 'system.__comobject' to interface type 'adodb recordset'

Anyone have a clue on how to fix it?

Edit:
There is no code because the error doesnt happens when i debug/run it, it happen when after i installed my program on the server machine and i try to run it but on my machine it is fine

Comment: No clue I'm afraid. You don't give any code, explain which line of code generates the error, or in fact give any details at all. Do you want us to guess?!  Please try harder to explain your problem.  It will take you some time. You will have to invest some time and effort.

Comment: what happens if you compile it on the 2008 server?

Comment: Then it will work.  Windows 7 SP1 contains a long overdue update to ADO to deal with some pretty nasty 64-bit compatibility problems.  You need to update the ADO version on the server to match.  Review KB 983246

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADODB COM object not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745007/adodb-com-object-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the W2008 system have ADO to begin with? ADO comes with the package known as "MS data access components". Also note the bitness - if your program is 32-bit, you need 32-bit ADO installed and vice versa; 32-bit ADO and 64-bit ADO are two different packages.

Comment: Here on StackOverflow, we say "thank you" by upvoting or accepting the answer :)

Comment: Does that mean it is the right answer or that you appreciate an answer?

Comment: @Seva OP doesn't have enough rep to up-vote, and this may not yet solve the problem. Be patient!